# how to fix "Exception raised during rendering: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DLNs.png)I think the problem was that I updated to a new version of Android Studio in the middle of the project, maybe that's why the view group didn't appear, What should I do?

Comment: Post the code where error is being thrown. Add stack traces to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post the code of layout file which causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Studio is simply telling the problem, that View can not be casted to ViewGroup, you must have done that somewhere in your code, fix that.